# Access 2013 VBA: Complie error: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having an issue with a button on a 2013 Access form.

High level: I am making some regulatory forms, 1 is a service Request, the other is a complaint request.
A service request is opened on every service call, if the call is not for a part replacement, it also generates a general complaint request.

I have a form "service_request_form" which is where techs fill out the info. There is a button on this form which i would like to copy all data from this service form and generate a complaint request record. From there it closes all windows, and prints out 2 custom reports based on our paper records.

Issue: I am recieving "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" on line

`Private Sub GenerateComplaint_Click()`

This is my first attempt at vba, so please bear with me, I am not a developer.

Below is VBA for the button:

```
Private Sub GenerateComplaint_Click()
If IsNull([txtAddress]) Or IsNull([txtCity]) Or IsNull([txtCompany]) Or IsNull([txtContact]) Or IsNull([txtDescription]) Or IsNull([txtEmail]) Or IsNull([txtPhoneNumber]) Or IsNull([txtPartNumberOrModel]) Or IsNull([txtSerialNumber]) Or IsNull([txtService Request Date]) Or IsNull([txtState]) Or IsNull([txtZip]) Then
MsgBox "Somethings not right"

Else
 DoCmd.Save
 Dim Prompt As Integer
 Prompt = InputBox("Are you Sure you would like to create a Complaint Record? Type 1 for yes, 0 for No")
    If Prompt = 1 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Complaint Request Form", , , , acFormAdd
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Company = Me.txtCompany
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Address = Me.txtAddress
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Contact = Me.txtContact
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Phone = Me.txtPhone
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Email = Me.txtEmail
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.ProductNumber = Me.txtPartNumberOrModel
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.SerialNumber = Me.txtSerialNumber
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.City = Me.txtCity
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.State = Me.txtState
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Zip = Me.txtZip
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Description = Me.txtDescription
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.CusDescription = Me.txtCusDescription
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.ServiceRequestNumber = Me.ServiceRequestDate
         Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.ComplaintRequestDate = Me.txtService_Request_Date

        Dim SN As Long
        SN = Me.ServiceRequestNumber
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Complaint Request Form", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Service_Request_sub", acSaveYes
        'DoCmd.OpenTable "Complaint_Request", , acReadOnly
        'DoCmd.Close acTable, "Complaint_Request", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenReport "ComplaintRequestReport", acViewPreview, , "[Complaint_Request]![ServiceRequestNum]=" & SN
        'DoCmd.OpenReport "ServiceRequestReport", acViewPreview, , "[Service_Request]![ServiceRequestNumber]=" & SN
        'Below line works, I think there is a data type issue, ServiceRequest!ServiceRequestNumber is an autonumber, Where complaintRequest!ServiceRequestNum is autonumber
        DoCmd.OpenReport "ServiceRequestReport", acViewPreview, , "[Service_Request]![ServiceRequestNumber]=" & SN
        'DoCmd.Close acForm, "Service_Request_sub"
    ElseIf Promp = 0 Then
    'do nothing'
    Else
    Prompt = InputBox("Are you Sure you would like to create a Complaint     Record? Type 1 for yes, 0 for No")
    End If




End If

End Sub
```

Running

```
Private Sub GenerateComplaint_Click()
If IsNull([txtAddress]) Or IsNull([txtCity]) Or IsNull([txtCompany]) Or IsNull([txtContact]) Or IsNull([txtDescription]) Or IsNull([txtEmail]) Or IsNull([txtPhoneNumber]) Or IsNull([txtPartNumberOrModel]) Or IsNull([txtSerialNumber]) Or IsNull([txtService Request Date]) Or IsNull([txtState]) Or IsNull([txtZip]) Then
MsgBox "Somethings not right"
End if
```

Works just fine.

Comment: Looks like it works... I mean, it *generates a [compiler] complaint* right? `</dad-joke>` ...Are you *sure* the highlighted line is the method's *signature*? First time I hear that happening...

Comment: That said all these `Set` keywords will cause a runtime error once you get it to compile and run. `Set` is for assigning *object references*, and you're assigning *values*. Remove `Set` there.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I created a new "blank" button, which was called GenerateComplaint. 
    I pasted the first If statement, and the button worked as expected. The button was created by VBA

Comment: Did you double-click the button and let VBA create that click handler for you, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: Wait, so it *does* compile and run? There are two types of errors: a *compile* error makes the code impossible to run. A *runtime* error blows up the program while it's running. Your question mentions a *compile* error, but then you're saying you get it to display a message box.... what's the exact issue you're having?

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect the testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time.

To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

And read: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Phone = Me.txtPhone
```

should have been

```
Forms![Complaint Request Form].Form.Phone = Me.txtPhoneNumber
```

Sorry for wasting your time.