# MS Access - Automatic email templates with Outlook

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, ms-access-2010

I have attempted to modify the code in [Sorceri's answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973549/ms-access-vba-sending-an-email-through-outlook), which demonstrates how to send an email using outlook. I tried to modify this to provide a custom email template, specific to the selected entry in the database:

```
Private Sub Emailtemplatebtn_Click()

Dim App As Outlook.Application
Dim Mail As MailItem
Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set Mail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.Body = "Dear" &[Forename]& "," &vbCrLf& &vbCrLf& "It has been six months or longer since I last contacted you. Have there been any big gains with regard to impact?"
oMail.Subject = &[Project name]& "- check up"
oMail.To = &Email&
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work. The in-built VBA editor highlights the lines "oMail.Body", "oMail.subject", and "oMail.to" in red.

I figure that this could be a very helpful feature, as it will save users even more time - the script/database will essentially handle all of the user's copy and pasting!

---

**Solution**

After using "Option Explicit", it seemed to be easier to locate why the code was failing - variables were not properly defined (I added some "o"s, and took some away). Here is the finished code:

1. Put "Option Explicit" at the top of the VBA page for the form (the module for the form)
2. Use the following code, largely corrected by Andre.

   Private Sub Emailtemplatebtn_Click()

   ```
   Dim App As Outlook.Application
   Dim oMail As MailItem
   Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.application")


   Set oMail = App.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   oMail.Body = "Dear" & Me![Forename] & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "It has been six months or longer since I last contacted you. Have there been any big gains with regard to impact?"
   oMail.Subject = Me![Project name] & "- check up"
   oMail.To = Me!Email
   oMail.Send
   Set oMail = Nothing
   Set App = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

Change `oMail.send` to `oMail.display` if you wish to make edits to the email before sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
Dim oMail As MailItem
```

(note the "o")

And the syntax for `&` is `variable & "string"`, note the spaces and don't use two `&` in a row.

Those lines should be:

```
oMail.Body = "Dear" & [Forename] & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "It has been six months or longer since I last contacted you. Have there been any big gains with regard to impact?"
oMail.Subject = [Project name] & "- check up"
oMail.To = Email
```

If the variables are controls on your form, it is better to write `Me!Forename` or `Me![Project name]` so Access knows where to look for them.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can you clarify what you mean about the &, variables, and strings (Ideally by editing a line of my code, e.g. oMail.body).

Comment: Thank you very much for the code - I see exactly how to implement the &s now (although, your explanation should have allowed me to get it right, too!).

Comment: I removed a lot of "me!"s from my "me![...]"s in my code, because it seemed easier to read and Access was able to find the correct fields without any problems (perhaps it assumes me!). Why is it advantageous to use me!, and what is a control exactly? A third question: What's the difference between "me!Forename" and "me![Forename]"?

Comment: In `oMail.To = Email`, *Email* could be anything - a variable, a global constant, a form control. By writing `Me!Email` you tell Access and anyone who reads your code that it is a form control (= something on your form, a textbox or combobox etc.). The square brackets are needed if the control name contains spaces, `Me![Project name]`.

Comment: That might allow me to make my code more efficient, then. It may even fix some problems I was having with conditional formatting (unresolved ^^).

Comment: Andre, do you have any idea why I receive the error "Run-time error '424': Object required"? The line highlighted in debugging is: "
Set Mail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)".

Comment: Same reason, oApp vs. App. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/38002045/3820271

Comment: I put "Option Explicit" at the start of the sub, and got the error "Invalid inside procedure" - which I can't find how to fix. Did I take the right bit of code from that thread?

Comment: It must go at the top of each **module**, not sub.

Comment: I don't have any modules yet - if you have any advice on what I need to get this to work, that'd be (again) much appreciated. I'll try and find out on my own, too.

Comment: All code is in a module, standard module or form module. Just press Ctrl+Home and there it goes. :)

Comment: Ah, so does it replace the default "Option Compare Database", or does it go at the start with it? (p.s., Ctrl+Home takes the user to the top of the VBA module - extra info for other users of the site)

Comment: Great, I got it to work! I'll add my final code to my question.