# Importing using VB not manual import

Tags: vba, ms-access, import

I currently know how to import these files manually, but I am looking to execute a vb code through my import button to do it automatically. There is a field linked to the import button which requires you to enter a date and click import. Once import is clicked, I would like it to grab a file based on the date that is on the files name.

These files are text files and the file names are written in two types of format:

1st Format - P.RR1234.ABCDEF.D160112.T123456

2nd Format - G1234.ABCDEF.D160112.T123456

Here is my vb code for my current form (I currently have it mapped to my desktop but there are 100's of files located on a network/shared path that are in the format):

```
          Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

On Error GoTo Click_Err

    If Nz(txtReportDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "NOTICE! Please enter the Report Month you wish to Import."

        Else

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    'Loop through recordset of all Contracts and import files
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT FROM AAAAB_CE"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While rs.EOF = False
            ImportFile rs!DISTINCT
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "Finished Importing!"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "query_Files_Loaded_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly

click_Exit:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

Click_Err:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    MsgBox "Error Detected: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume click_Exit

       Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Public Function ImportFile(Contract As String)

DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "123_Files", "AAAAB_CE", "C:\Users\123456\Desktop\TestingFolder\test.txt", False

End Function
```

I am trying to import these text files into one table. There are a lot of files, so manually would be insufficient.

Currently, if I put in a random date on the form text date and click import. It imports the file I select, but in a completely wrong format. Which is weird because the specification I saved was done in the correct format.

All in all I am trying to accomplish three things.

1) Import automatically by entering a date in a field on form (the date will be part of the file name) and clicking the import buton
2) Import the text file in the correct structure, fixed columns
3) If an incorrect date is entered, do not import anything.

Comment: I re-did the import spec and now it says the spec does not exist when clicking import, but the spec does exist.

Comment: 1)+3) and 2) are very different, unrelated issues. Please separate them into two questions. For 2) we will need your table structure, the input format, and the import specification (see https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-do-you-print-an-import-specification.3120686/ )

Comment: @Andre My table is 20 columns (with the last two columns being the import date and filename. All columns are text, except ImportDate which is Date/Time). What more information can I provide you for the table structure? The text files are setup to match the table. When I manually import it (it’s a fixed textile), I am now able to import it correctly.

Comment: @Andre What do you mean by input format? As in the how you type the date in the field on my form? If so, it should be MMDDYYYY. Also, for import specification,  I am using access, how can I use that SQL statement you provided to give me my specification?  I run the query in my module and form, I get no results. Saved imports does not show details of my spec.
My specification is saved as:
Which questions should I open a new thread for? Questions 1 and 3?

Comment: @Andre I am currently re-doing the manual import and when I click advance, I get a message stating that the subscript is out of range. I think this is where I get the spec for you.

Comment: @Andre In all the text files, first column always has the #1. I am assuming this is causing an issue? We call this one a Record Type.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't troubleshoot this code without knowing the date format used in the txt files and the files themselves, but this is how I would attack it:

- use Dir to loop through the files at specified folder location searching for .txt files that contains the date,
- then calling your ImportFile function (which is really a sub no?) by passing the filename.

Hopefully enough there for you to follow the logic..

```
Public Sub sampleSub()
Dim dirStr As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileDate As Date

filePath = "C:\Users\123456\Desktop\TestingFolder\"
On Error GoTo doNothing:
fileDate = DateValue(InputBox("NOTICE! Please enter the Report Month you wish to Import."))

dirStr = Dir(filePath & "\" & "*" * Format(fileDate, "FileDateFormat") & "*" & ".txt")
Do Until dirStr = ""
    Call ImportFile(dirStr)
Loop

Exit Sub
doNothing:
Call MsgBox("Error Detected: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")
End Sub

Public Sub ImportFile(fileName As String)
Call DoCmd.TransferText(acImportFixed, "123_Files", "AAAAB_CE", fileName, False)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode