# Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set Error Access Vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I tried reading other posted questions about this error but I am still having trouble understanding it.

I was having errors after renaming variables and posted this question, I use option explicit and debug my code and it fixed my naming problems, But I still am having one problem in that 2 out of my 21 comboboxes in the operations row are still getting this same error. How can they get an error when they are using the same functions as the other 19. I checked their names and they are correct how could this be??

I have a form that I have build that is set up to look and function similar to and excel spreadsheet. This is the layout, Column Names first and then Control type

```
Operation   Time/Min   DecTime    LaborRate   Cost    MarkUp    Total 
ComboBox     TextBox   Label       Label      Label   TextBox   Label
```

So all together I have 7 columns with 21 rows (not including column names) in which I can input data. Any where there is a label there is no user input its value is simply derived from the other fields.

I used the following naming convention for my form controls cb_op1, cb_op2, cb_op3 ... I just increment it by one to mimic the row number (control name plus row number). Operation = cb_op, Time = tb_time, DecTime = tb_Dectime,  LaborRate = tb_LbrRate, Cost = tb_Cost,  MarkUp = tb_MU, Total = tb_Total.

I wrote functions for the AfterUpdate events for my controls. This first function gets the value of the control based on its row number and then allows me to assign it to a variable this fuction is used for multiple controls update events.

```
Private Function GetControlValue(name As String) As Object

    Dim obj As Object

    For Each obj In Me.Controls
        If obj.name = name Then
            Set GetControlValue = obj
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

The next function is used to actually update the other field in the row based on the after update event. I use the GetControlValue Function listed above in this function. This is just for the operations column.

```
Private Function OperationsUpdate(RowNumber As Integer)

 Dim Operations As Object
 Dim Time As Object
 Dim DecTime As Object
 Dim LaborRate As Object

 Set Operations = GetControlValue("cb_op" & RowNumber)
 Set Time = GetControlValue("tb_time" & RowNumber)
 Set DecTime = GetControlValue("tb_DecTime" & RowNumber)
 Set LaborRate = GetControlValue("tb_LbrRate" & RowNumber)
 Set Cost = GetControlValue("tb_Cost" & RowNumber)

    If IsNull(Time.Value) Then
        If IsNull(Operation.Value) Then
            Cost.Value = ""
            LaborRate.Value = ""
        Else
            LaborRate.Value = DLookup("LaborRate", "OperationsType", "[operationsID] = " & Operation.Value)
        End If
    Else
        If IsNull(Operation.Value) Then
            Cost.Value = ""
            LaborRate.Value = ""
        Else
            LaborRate.Value = DLookup("LaborRate", "OperationsType", "[operationsID] = " & Operation.Value)
            Cost.Value = DecTime.Value * LaborRate.Value
        End If
    End If

    FormObjectsUpdate2 (RowNumber)

 Set Operations = Nothing
 Set Time = Nothing
 Set DecTime = Nothing
 Set LaborRate = Nothing
 Set Cost = Nothing

End Function
```

Finally this is how my After update events look per control. I post just the first three not all 21 to save space.

```
Private Sub cb_op1_AfterUpdate()
    OperationsUpdate (1)
End Sub

Private Sub cb_op2_AfterUpdate()
    OperationsUpdate (2)
End Sub

Private Sub cb_op3_AfterUpdate()
    OperationsUpdate (3)
End Sub
```

I just posted the function and the code for the first column operations all the other after update events are now having the same issues too.

Comment: You need to account for the case of `GetControlValue` returning `Nothing`.

Comment: Just to be sure, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38002045/3820271

Comment: This help to clean things up but now I have it to where cb_op18 and cb_op21 now have the error but not the others. How could just two out of 21 have this error but they using the same functions. I had this same problem before I Changed my variables

Comment: Likely some of your controls are not correctly named on rows 18 and 21.  As a check, add `Msgbox "Not found: " & name` just before `End Function` in `GetControlValue`

Comment: That worked, I was just checking the names of the operations combobox which were correct, but I did not check the other names in the calculations which I found two errors.